# Respond to the statement with so am i or so do i

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions, answers

What would be the correct way to respond the statement "I usually start at 8.00 a.m. in the morning"

should i answer with so am I or so do i?

Comment: By the way, "8 a.m. in the morning" is redundant - 8 a.m. always means "in the morning", and "in the morning" could only mean a.m.

Comment: @stangdon: Except in those rare cases when the earth has stopped rotating normally.    ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Your response should be **"So do I".**

The response to "I am starting at 8 in the morning" would be "so am I".

You can see the pattern:

"I *do something*"

"So do I"

"I am *doing something*"

"So am I"

Comment: or more informally, "Me too." or "Ditto."